# Is there a conductive spray (not paint, ink and tape, only spray)?

Tags: conductive

I heard that there is a conductive spray. 
So I'm looking for a conductive spray (not paint,ink and tape). 
But I could not find sites for selling conductive sprays.

I bought a silver zinc coat spray. I sprayed on the paper and tested for conductivity. Unfortunately, the electricity did not flow.

Does anyone know sites for selling conductive sprays?

Please, let me know sites for selling conductive sprays.

Comment: I don't necessarily see this as a shopping question, but rather a plea for how to search for the product the OP is looking for.  Teach if possible.

Comment: I know you said "no paint." But I have heard of conductive paint which can be sprayed. Unfortunately I don't have any specific details that would help you.

Comment: Defined desired properties 1st in measurable detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend.  Pounding the string "conductive spray" into Google brings up a page full of results.

The first result on that page is [MG Chemicals 841 Nickel spray](http://www.mgchemicals.com/products/emi-and-rfi-shielding/other-coating-systems/super-shield-nickel-841)

I have used that product several times and it works well.